# Elastisearch Enabling Remote Connection - Crashes AFTER Change*

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, remote-access

I just installed filebeat, logstash, kibana and elasticsearch all running smoothly just to trial this product out for additional monthly reports/monitoring and noticed every time I try to change the "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml" config file for remote web access it'll basically crash the service every time I make the change.

Just want to say I'm new to the forum and this product, and my end goal for this question is to figure out how to allow remote connections to access elastisearch as I guinea pig and test without crashing elasticsearch.

For reference here is the error code when I run the 'sudo systemctl status elasticsearch' query:

Dec 30 07:27:37 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Dec 30 07:27:52 ubuntu systemd-entrypoint[4067]: ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
Dec 30 07:27:52 ubuntu systemd-entrypoint[4067]: bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.se>
Dec 30 07:27:52 ubuntu systemd-entrypoint[4067]: ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Dec 30 07:27:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Dec 30 07:27:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 30 07:27:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question with the content of your `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, mostly had to do with the 'network.host' being set to '0.0.0.0' for my test environment.  Thank you for replying though.